# Textwatcher - Different Last Char Situations

Tags: android, textwatcher

Long story short I am facing this problem: I am attaching a textwatcher to an edittext. As soon as "1" is the last char written on it, that should be replaced with the letter "a". But here is the problem: I'd like as soon as "a" is also the last char written on the edittext (user pressed "a"), EXCEPT THROUGH THE PREVIOUS METHOD, some things to be done. But as I test it and type "1", that is converted to "a" normally and the things I mention are also done. I can't seem to find a way to overpass this, can any suggestions be given? Thanks a lot. I use:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == '1') {
        current_string = s.toString().substring(0, (s.length() - 1));
        et.setText(current_string + "a");
        length = s.length();
        et.setSelection(length);
    }
    else if (s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == 'a') {
        //do some things
    }
```

Comment: "I'd like as soon as "a" is also the last char written on the edittext" 
what does this mean ? what do you want to do when a is written on the end ?

Comment: don't think it matters at all, just some thing that should be done when "a" is pressed directly

Comment: do that check on onTextChanged method of textwatcher

Comment: tried it before and doesn't work too

Comment: Use the first if clause and in there also set a boolean flag. In the else clause after the current checks also check that boolean flag to see if the last action wasn't the `1` replacement.

Comment: Thought that too. To say flag = false in the first if statement and then if (flag) on the second, do things. But then how could I set flag back to true everytime a is pressed directly from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean.

1)when user enters the 1 in end  it should replace by 'a'.
2)when user enters 'a' separately (not converted by the step 1) it should do something else

```
amount1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            int flagg;

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                System.out.println("flagg"+s+"#"+flagg );
                if (s.length() > 0  && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == '1' )
                {   System.out.println("Converting and doing NOthing");
                    flagg=1;
                    String current_string = s.toString().substring(0,(s.length() - 1));
                    amount1.setText(current_string + "a");
                    int length = s.length();
                    amount1.setSelection(length);

                } 
                else if (s.length() > 0     && ( s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == 'a') && flagg == 0 )  {
                    System.out.println("Staying same and doing Something");

                    amount2.setText(amount2.getText().toString() + "Z");
                    // do some things
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

                if (start != 0) {

                    if ((s.toString()).substring(s.length() - 1).equals("a")) {
                        flagg = 1;
                    }
                    if ((s.toString()).substring(s.length() - 1).equals("1")) {
                        flagg = 0;
                    } else {
                        flagg = 0;
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
        });

//new flagg is set in if condition
```

Comment: If I put "a" it executes thinzg normally. Then if I put "1" it isn't converted to "a" but it gives "1" =/

Comment: "1" gives "a" but triggers the done things as well, like my posted code :/ I'mma do bounty for this question, solution may be simple, may be not, it sure has to do with if statements but I lack programming knowledge as I am really amateur. really, really thanks for your help tho

Comment: can u explain me once again if i m wrong .. if user enters "111"
 it should become "aaa" without doing "something" ,and when user enters "aaa" it should remain same and do "something",

Comment: yeap, exactly. To your example, user enters "1" → "a", then "1" → "a", "1" → "a", "a" → "a" (no change) + something else, "a" → "a" + something else, "a" → "a" + something else, etc.

Comment: @user3265784  sorry , i for got to add set flag in if condtion

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

if (s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == 'a') {
       //do some things
}
if (s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == '1') {
    current_string = s.toString().substring(0, (s.length() - 1));
    et.setText(current_string + "a");
    length = s.length();
     et.setSelection(length);

}
```

Comment: what does it say when you press a? what is your code in //do some things ?

Comment: it does not matter. Let's say, set the text of a different edittext, et2.setText("WRONG");

Comment: well if it works for 1 it should work for a too, if there is no error i dont know what to say, put a Log.d("IT Works",""); inside //do some things ad check if the flow goes there, if ti does then the problem is with how you do those things